# Multiple-attr unique constraint prevents row insertion due to "duplicate" error

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema, unique-constraint

This is what my table looks like:

```
   id   user_id event_id    
    4   0       10 
    3   1       8 
    1   2       8 
    2   3       8 
    5   4       10 
    6   5       5
```

I've applied the unique constraint on (user_id, event_id) combination (multiple users can be invited to multiple events, but a user cannot be invited to the same event twice):

```
ALTER TABLE `Event_Invited` ADD Unique(`event_id`, `user_id`)
```

I am trying to insert a new record/row with values `event_id` = 8 and `user_id` = 4 
Which should be fine, but I am getting the error:

```
"Duplicate entry '4' for key 'user_id_3'
```

Why?
At first I thought I accidentally set a UNIQUE constraint specifically to the `users_id` column, but even after I made sure I have that removed, I am still getting these errors.

**Edit:** It seems as though I am getting this error because I have some constraint not allowing me to have records with the same `user_id` value. Does the constraint I specified above makes the values in each column unique, rather than making their combination unique?

Comment: do you have a column named 'user_id_3' ? using your code it runs fine <a href="http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37c45/1/0">here</a>

Comment: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37c45/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `Event_Invited` ADD Unique index(`event_id`, `user_id`)
```

Check out [13.1.8. CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more